# Pipe delimited file to csv using sed in windows

Tags: csv, sed, cmd

sample file

```
NFTY|First Trust India Nifty 50 Equal Weight ETF|G|N|N|100|Y|N
NGHC|National General Holdings Corp - Common Stock|G|N|N|100|N|N
```

desired

```
NFTY,First Trust India Nifty 50 Equal Weight ETF,G,N,N,100,Y,N
NGHC,National General Holdings Corp - Common Stock,G,N,N,100,N,N
```

Works in bash but not windows

```
sed 's/^/"/;s/|/","/g;s/$/"/' file
```

error in windows

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Comment: Just to be clear, we're talking about running `sed` in the MS-DOS prompt here? I'm guessing its something to do with how the shell is interpreting your quotes in and around the regular expression.

Comment: my particular os is windows 10, sed gnu v 4.4

Comment: I don't necessarily have to do this in sed.  I just can't use the (csv) file as is due to specifying the deliminator as | in psql's copy command breaks my scripting (pipe's in scripts are interpreted as system signals) and I'm not sure how to address it (using psql to import a csv file).

Comment: we want to know where you are tying this command - ex: git-bash, linux subsystem for windows, cygwin, dos-prompt, etc... does `sed "s/^/\"/;s/|/\",\"/g;s/$/\"/"` work?

Comment: command prompt cmd.exe, "the network path was not found" sed "s/^/\"/;s/|/\",\"/g;s/$/\"/" < c:\test\nasdaqSymbols.txt

Comment: I don't know about cmd.exe .. hopefully someone else would help you out.. I'd suggest to install git-bash or linux subsystem for windows so that you can use same syntax as you are used to on linux..

Comment: I'm trying to port this to a least common denominator platform.  I thought about moving it to all linux, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I don't have a Windows box handy to test this on, but I think the problem is probably that [the escape character in Windows is `^`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#escape). Can you try `sed 's/^^/"/;s/|/","/g;s/$/"/' file`? (the difference being two `^` characters instead of one to put a literal `^` into the argument)

Comment: 's/^^/"/;s/|/","/g;s/$/"/' That was it!

Comment: Anyway to get it to NOT put quotes around everything in the output.  Example "LGIH","LGI Homes, Inc. - Common Stock","Q","N","N","100","N","N"
"LGND","Ligand Pharmaceuticals Incorporated - Common Stock","G","N","N","100","N","N"

Comment: was able to remove the annoying quotes (lucky for me source file had none originally) using: sed 's/^^/"/;s/|/;/g;s/$/"/' c:\test\nasdaqSymbols.txt | tr -d '"'

Comment: I'm glad it solved the problem. Please accept my answer below, which basically just restates the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The escape character in Windows is `^`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#escape), which means that the argument to `sed` is being passed as `s//"/;s/|/","/g;s/$/"/`, because the `^` is simply escaping the slash following it. Add another `^` before that one (`sed 's/^^/"/;s/|/","/g;s/$/"/' file`) so that you get a literal `^` in the argument.

(The error "no previous regular expression" is because if you pass an empty matching regex to `sed`'s `s` command it uses the last matching regex you used in the session, but there isn't one here.)